# Is there a way to add empty rows in a dataframe based on a set of conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate work done on a specific task by a person in weekly intervals, but I can only retrieve cumulative data every week. I will get a table that looks something like this for week 1

**Week 1 Data**

```
week1 = pd.read_csv(Week1data.csv)
display(week1)

name ,task, date       , hours ,
Bob  , a  , 10/28/2020 , 8     ,
Bob  , b  , 10/23/2020 , 8     ,
Bob  , c  , 10/22/2020 , 8     ,
David, a  , 10/12/2020 , 8     ,
David, b  , 10/20/2020 , 8     ,
David, d  , 10/28/2020 , 8     ,
David, f  , 10/24/2020 , 8     ,
Allen, b  , 10/08/2020 , 8     ,
Allen, d  , 10/18/2020 , 8     ,
Kora , a  , 10/21/2020 , 8     ,
Kora , d  , 10/23/2020 , 8     ,
Ash  , a  , 10/02/2020 , 8     ,
Ash  , b  , 10/08/2020 , 8     ,
Ash  , e  , 10/13/2020 , 8     ,
```

and I'll get a table like this for week 2

**Week 2 Data**
:notice that people have conducted new tasks as well as accumulated more hours for previously conducted tasks as well as new people who have conducted tasks

```
week2 = pd.read_csv(Week2data.csv)
display(week2)

name ,task, date       , hours ,
Bob  , a  , 11/01/2020 , 12    ,
Bob  , b  , 10/30/2020 , 15    ,
Bob  , c  , 10/30/2020 , 9     ,
Bob  , d  , 11/03/2020 , 5     ,
David, a  , 11/05/2020 , 10    ,
David, b  , 11/03/2020 , 9     ,
David, d  , 11/01/2020 , 15    ,
David, f  , 10/30/2020 , 18    ,
Becca, a  , 11/04/2020 , 8     ,
Becca, c  , 11/04/2020 , 3     ,
Allen, b  , 11/04/2020 , 14    ,
Allen, d  , 11/04/2020 , 10    ,
Kora , a  , 11/01/2020 , 12    ,
Kora , d  , 11/03/2020 , 9     ,
Ash  , a  , 11/02/2020 , 15    ,
Ash  , b  , 11/08/2020 , 18    ,
Ash  , e  , 11/03/2020 , 11    ,
Tim  , a  , 11/01/2020 , 8     ,
Tim  , b  , 11/03/2020 , 6     ,
```

I can't simply get the difference between the hours columns between the two dataframes. If I just subtract Week2['hours'] - Week1['hours'], after a few rows I will be subtracting the hours that 'Bob' worked on task 'd' from the hours that 'David' worked on task 'a'. This would be incorrect.

I want to add an empty row in the week 1 data where there is a new employee or where there is a new task that an employee did and then take the difference.
After the empty rows have been added.

The adjusted week 1 table should look something like this

```
name ,task, date       , hours ,
Bob  , a  , 10/28/2020 , 8     ,
Bob  , b  , 10/23/2020 , 8     ,
Bob  , c  , 10/22/2020 , 8     ,
Nan  , Nan, Nan        , 0     ,
David, a  , 10/12/2020 , 8     ,
David, b  , 10/20/2020 , 8     ,
David, d  , 10/28/2020 , 8     ,
David, f  , 10/24/2020 , 8     ,
Nan  , Nan, Nan        , 0     ,
Nan  , Nan, Nan        , 0     ,
Allen, b  , 10/08/2020 , 8     ,
Allen, d  , 10/18/2020 , 8     ,
Kora , a  , 10/21/2020 , 8     ,
Kora , d  , 10/23/2020 , 8     ,
Ash  , a  , 10/02/2020 , 8     ,
Ash  , b  , 10/08/2020 , 8     ,
Ash  , e  , 10/13/2020 , 8     ,
Nan  , Nan, Nan        , 0     ,
Nan  , Nan, Nan        , 0     ,
```

The week 1,2,3,n interval columns would be added to its own dataframe

Week 1 Interval Column would look something like this after I take, and something similar for week 2,3,n.

```
Week 1 Interval = Week2['hours'] - Week1['hours']

week 1 interval,
4,
7,
1,
5,
2,
1,
7,
10,
8,
3,
6,
2,
4,
1,
7,
10,
3,
8,
```

Comment: I think you need to give more information on the calculation you require, but if the problem is simply matching the two week, doesn't merging the two data frames with 'how=outer' let you achieve that? df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['name', 'task'])

Comment: By doing that I am unable to to calculate the difference between the weeks. I will update what the week1 interval column should look like.

Comment: I revised the initial question so that it is more clear. I am given two CSVs, week 1 has total hours worked till 10/20/20, and week 2 has total hours worked till 10/27/2020. I need to calculate the difference in hours worked so that I can see how many hours each person worked on the given task. I figured I should also update you on my question as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem now, and I still think you can use merge, since the outer merge will create the empty cells you want on week 1, which you can fillna with 0 and do your calculations. I'll post it as an answer, check and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating the empty rows in week 1 you can use outer merge:

```
df = week1.merge(week2, how='outer', on=['name', 'task'], suffixes=['_w1', '_w2']).sort_values(['name', 'task'])

df.hours_w1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Now you have matching rows for each name/task for each week for every task they have done. Then you can simply calculate the difference:

```
df['interval'] = df['hours_w2'] - df['hours_w1']
```

The result will look like this:

```
     name  task       date_w1  hours_w1       date_w2  hours_w2  interval
7   Allen   b     10/08/2020        8.0   11/04/2020         14       6.0
8   Allen   d     10/18/2020        8.0   11/04/2020         10       2.0
11  Ash     a     10/02/2020        8.0   11/02/2020         15       7.0
12  Ash     b     10/08/2020        8.0   11/08/2020         18      10.0
13  Ash     e     10/13/2020        8.0   11/03/2020         11       3.0
15  Becca   a             NaN       0.0   11/04/2020          8       8.0
16  Becca   c             NaN       0.0   11/04/2020          3       3.0
0   Bob     a     10/28/2020        8.0   11/01/2020         12       4.0
1   Bob     b     10/23/2020        8.0   10/30/2020         15       7.0
2   Bob     c     10/22/2020        8.0   10/30/2020          9       1.0
14  Bob     d             NaN       0.0   11/03/2020          5       5.0
3   David   a     10/12/2020        8.0   11/05/2020         10       2.0
4   David   b     10/20/2020        8.0   11/03/2020          9       1.0
5   David   d     10/28/2020        8.0   11/01/2020         15       7.0
6   David   f     10/24/2020        8.0   10/30/2020         18      10.0
9   Kora    a     10/21/2020        8.0   11/01/2020         12       4.0
10  Kora    d     10/23/2020        8.0   11/03/2020          9       1.0
17  Tim     a             NaN       0.0   11/01/2020          8       8.0
18  Tim     b             NaN       0.0   11/03/2020          6       6.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I used the code that you gave me and used it in production scenario and it worked relatively well. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Using you example, i hope this help you:

```
week1 = [("Bob", "a", "10/28/2020", 8),
    ("Bob", "b", "10/23/2020", 8),
    ("Bob", "c", "10/22/2020", 8),
    ("David", "a", "10/12/2020", 8),
    ("David", "b", "10/20/2020", 8),     
    ("David", "d", "10/28/2020", 8),     
    ("David", "f", "10/24/2020", 8),     
    ("Allen", "a", "10/08/2020", 8),    
    ("Allen", "d", "10/18/2020", 8),     
    ("Kora", "a", "10/21/2020", 8),     
    ("Kora", "d", "10/23/2020", 8),     
    ("Ash", "a", "10/02/2020", 8),    
    ("Ash", "b", "10/08/2020", 8),    
    ("Ash", "e", "10/13/2020", 8)]
    
    week1 = pd.DataFrame(week1, columns=["name" ,"task", "date", "hours"])
    week1["week"] = 1
    
    week2 = [("Bob", "a", "11/01/2020", 12),
    ("Bob", "b", "10/30/2020", 15),
    ("Bob", "c", "10/30/2020", 9),
    ("Bob", "d", "11/03/2020", 5),
    ("David", "a", "11/05/2020", 10),
    ("David", "b", "11/03/2020", 9),
    ("David", "d", "11/01/2020", 15),
    ("David", "f", "10/30/2020", 18),
    ("Becca", "a", "11/04/2020", 8),
    ("Becca", "c", "11/04/2020", 3),
    ("Allen", "b", "11/04/2020", 14),
    ("Allen", "d", "11/04/2020", 10),
    ("Kora" , "a", "11/01/2020", 12),
    ("Kora" , "d", "11/03/2020", 9),
    ("Ash"  , "a", "11/02/2020", 15),
    ("Ash"  , "b", "11/08/2020", 18),
    ("Ash"  , "e", "11/03/2020", 11),
    ("Tim"  , "a", "11/01/2020", 8),
    ("Tim"  , "b", "11/03/2020", 6)]
    
    week2 = pd.DataFrame(week2, columns=["name" ,"task", "date", "hours"])
    week2["week"] = 2
   
    df = pd.concat([week1, week2])
    df = df[["name", "task", "hours", "week"]]
    pd.pivot_table(df, index=["name", "task"], values='hours', columns='week', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

[Merge output without fillna()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFasJ.png)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I need to retain the granularity between the each person and how much time they spent on a task. If a new task is conducted by the individual I need to know how many hours they spent on that task, and if they spent time on a task that they have worked on previously then I need to know how much time they spent on that task. I've tried grouping and merging dataframes, but I don't get the desired result.

Comment: I tried using numpy.where so that if two conditions are met then the value from week 1 is written in it's own column, and if the condition is not met then 0 is written in the new column. However, it doesn't continue to check the same row against week 2. It will move to the next row and shift the hours values.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, maybe we need an example of the input with your desire output.

Comment: I revised the initial question so that it is more clear. I am given two CSVs, week 1 has total hours worked till 10/20/20, and week 2 has total hours worked till 10/27/2020. I need to calculate the difference in hours worked so that I can see how many hours each person worked on the given task.